# url changing without hash-bangs and fragments

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, url-rewriting

After reading online about hash-bangs. Ive decided to stick with our current url structure. Ive been developing a site and making it completely non-javascript. Im coming to a stage where i can start to upgrade some stuff to fancy javascript and ajaxy stuff.

To give a little info. Basically when a user visits the site, the homepage is the main area. It has some statistics and a box. In this box is a companys details with some call to action buttons (go to map, contact, e.c.t.).

When searching for a company, or directly linking to a company you go to

http://mysite.com/company/*company-name*

This is then url rewritten by apache to

http://mysite.com/index.php?company=*company-name*

Where then my php script loads the box up with teh company details e.c.t.

Now ive come to do some ajaxy stuff. I want users to be able to click company links on my site and also use the search without having to reload the page. So if they click on teh name of the top viewed company, a quick loading symbol goes in the box and then company details get loaded into that area.

Once again this isn't too much of an issue. I can do this many ways, classname binding or url regex binding with click handlers on anchors.

However, heres my problem. I need to be able to change the URL so it always reflects the the companys name. Users share links by copy and pasting urls. Even if i provide a "click to copy to clipboard" permalink button, they will hardly use it. Ebay is a classic example, they provide nice url's for sharing, but its common to see the long ones posted on forums around the place.

Hashbangs or another fragmented url approach would allow me to do this. and i could also attach javascript handlers to the document.load so i can populate the box when a user visits the site from a fragmented url. However if a non-javascript user visits the site using a fragmented url, they will just get the homepage and will have to manually search for teh company.

Given the time and effort ive put into doing everything non-js to begin with. I dont now want to ruin that or have to make a decision on whether to dump the non-js users. However ajax loaded content is very important and so is sharing url's.

The ideal solution would either be a way of php reading the fragmented url, or a way of javascript changing the url path

Can anyone help with this ?

P.S: apologies for the essay on this. just wanted to give as much info as possible and share the what ive found from research to save time going over things i may have already looked at

Comment: Read up: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: not really helpful diodeus, i know about mod rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the AJAX system I built WITHOUT using hashtags. It uses `window.history` in modern browsers and falls back for older ones that don't support cool AJAX stuff.

http://xeoncross.github.com/MicroStream/

You can see it live on my site: http://xeoncross.com

It's less than 10kB of simple, well commented code so you should be able to grasp it no problem.

Comment: Thanks, ive read heard about the history API. Never knew you could change thr url like that. However that doesn't satisfy my needs. Your ajax wont work if the history API is not supported. However IE9 (and <IE9) does support AJAX. So your stopping IE users from accessing fancy ajax loading. This is why i didnt want to go down any avenue that required HTML5. Thanks for your reply though ! Learned something from it at least

Comment: Actually @Lee, you can implement this regardless of how you handle the rest of the scheme. It degrades into standard browser loading for < IE9 so you have nothing to lose. You can add content AJAX widgets to this as well. It's the only way to support AJAX while keeping nice URL's.

Comment: i know i IE will degrade nicely to normal browser loading. However thats not what i want. IE supports ajax, but not the history API. Your code seems to require the history API for ajax to be used as it modifies the URL. If it wasnt for the history API requirement to keep the URL correct, it would be perfect for my needs. I think based on research however, i can use your method in firefox and chrome, and use a fragment in IE. This way whilst it isnt perfect, it will only be IE users that post links from the URL bar for non-js users that will cause issue.

Comment: Thats something i can live with. By allowing FF and chrome users to post url's using your code, it greatly reduces the chances of it happening. It forces it into the situation where the user that posts a link must be using IE (or an old browser) AND the person who clicks that link must have javascript disabled. That is going to be a very small percentage i imagine. Thanks for your reply, hopefully by combining different methods i have done everything i can to eliminate the issue the best i can

Comment: Please put some relevant code directly into your answer.